# How to make a 1 H, 10 A inductor

Tags: filter, inductor

I want to make a full-bridge rectifier with a pi filter. What are my options to make a 1 H, 10 A inductor with a small footprint?

Comment: Assuming the frequency is low such as 50, 60, or 400 Hz, a 1H / 10A inductor will not be small to have a PCB footprint. It'll be a large, heavy, iron-core inductor. I'm wondering why you need such high inductance. To get higher PF?

Comment: What kind full bridge? 3 Phases? Why do you need such an inductor?

Comment: If you have an unlimited supply of liquid nitrogen, research superconducting coils.

Comment: Why do you need such a high inductance? A pi filter's characteristics depend on both the inductance and the capacitance; I would think increasing the capacitance would be more practical.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - maybe you should step back, and ask a more general question regarding your design?

Comment: This can be deadly. Not only with its weight, but with its back-EMF as well.

Comment: To add to what @fraxinus said, look at this answer from Physics.SE: [What is the voltage of an average carpet static shock? Can you make it lethal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/244092/159294) And consider that your inductor would have 50 J to create a spark with.

Comment: A single AAA battery is enough to pump 50J in it.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a [0.1H 10A inductor](https://fr.farnell.com/en-FR/hammond/195t10/dc-filter-choke-0-1h-10a-15/dp/2546928). It weighs 35lbs.

There is a limit to the magnetic flux the magnetic core can handle. Above that it will saturate and inductance will decrease. Large value inductors require more turns which increase flux in the core. To avoid saturation, the flux per unit area in the core has to be kept below the saturation limit, which means a bigger core. Therefore, high value high current inductors tend to be huge, there's no way around it.

The only realistic way to make a filter at these frequencies is to use active devices, ie a voltage regulator. However, at high frequency, PSRR of voltage regulators decreases, which means a LC filter makes a great complement to enhance the high frequency rejection, as in this case the inductor and capacitor values become cheap and practical.

Comment: +1 OP just needs to mount 10 of those in series to get the desired inductance and current capability. Digikey even has them in stock, $3,650 US for the inductors and a bit more for a panel than can hold 350lb (160kg).

Answer (score 15):

I think your only option to get a small footprint 1H, 10A inductor is to redefine the word "small" to mean "humongous."

[This is a 1H, 240mA inductor](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/410/C_24X-1892581.pdf)

[image]

It is a box an inch and a half high, over two and a half inches wide, and  an inch and a hlaf thick (over 4 cm high, over 6 cm wide, and nearly 4 cm thick.) it weighs 0.75 pounds (over 300 grams.)

The one you want will have to handle over forty times as much current - it will be **much** larger and heavier.

Comment: +1 freely adapted from Spehro Pefhany: OP just needs to mount 42 of those in parallel for 10A and 42 such arrays in series to get the desired inductance and current capability. ... and a panel that can hold 530kg.

Answer (score 8):

Cryogenic cooling and superconducting wire.

A "small" footprint is indeed possible with this method.  Beware the stray fields: flux density inside the coil will be many tesla, and even at a few diameters' distance, the field strength will rival that of a NdFeB supermagnet of comparable size (i.e. of several coil diameters).

Number of turns, and size of wire, are left as exercise to the reader (or, anyone who feels sufficiently nerdsniped to edit this post :) ).  I would expect many thousands, and hair-fine, more or less.  Additional power will be required for the cryocooler.

Note that you are asking for -- assuming this is a choke-input rectifier application -- either a 10A supply with a critical current (minimum load for expected voltage regulation) of 1mA/V at 60Hz (multiply by Vrms input to get critical value), or a critical current somewhat less than 10A and therefore a supply voltage on the order of 5kV.  In the latter case, I would be more than happy to specify the stack of iron-core chokes identified in @bobflux's answer, and in that case, "small" would seem relative to a 50kW power supply or its load, which is probably a floor-standing rack type unit.  The voltage may be even higher if the supply is three-phase (which is very much desirable at these power levels).  Such would be adequate for a 100s kW vacuum tube oscillator/transmitter, for example.

Such voltages will substantially affect the design of the part (even the superconducting version will be MUCH larger, to fit enough insulation between layers), and a conventional iron-cored design will be nothing out of the ordinary as industrial equipment is concerned.  A custom wound unit may be more suitable than off-the-shelf parts.

Comment: It would have to be air-core too. Any small footprint's worth of ferrite or molypermalloy or what-have-you would saturate long before reaching 10 A.

Comment: @Hearth Good clarification: a superconducting inductor is usually air core. Even the best iron alloys peter out around 2T, while superconductors can go up to 10 or 20T; the additional 2 of a core is a drop in the bucket.

Comment: superconductors for this won't be small either. They are typically rather brittle. The large Lorentz force demands structural reinforcement to prevent coil implosion.

Comment: But what about the pcb footprint of the liquid helium cooler?

Comment: For some vaguely relevant context, a preclinical MRI scanner I work with has an inductance of 2.3 H and carries a superconducting DC current of about 500 amps. It is the size of a car and has a bore size of about 156 mm and thus you could consider it to be mostly air-cored...